# Django filter data in table based on value from another table?

Tags: python, django

views.py :

```
def dcuinterval(request):

var7 = dcu.objects.all()
MU_count = Meter_Mapping_Table.objects.filter(DCU_id=dcu.id).count()
d = {
    'MU_count': MU_count, 'var7': var7,
}
return render(request, 'dcu_interval.html', d)
```

Models.py:

```
class dcu(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(unique=True, editable=False, primary_key=True)
Asset = models.CharField(max_length=128)
IMEI_Number = models.CharField(max_length=128)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Asset

class Meter_Mapping_Table(models.Model):

mid = models.AutoField(unique=True, editable=False, primary_key=True)
Meter_id = models.CharField(
    max_length=128, help_text='(ID of the Meter table)')
MU_id = models.CharField(max_length=150)
DCU_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Meter_id
```

how to filter the data based on the another table filed ?

i need to filter the DCU_id based on the DCU tables id field
DCU_id =1;
DCU.id=1;
ANSWER:
MU_count=1
like this i need to filter and show that count

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```py
Meter_Mapping_Table.objects.filter(DCU_id='1').count()
```

Although that is the answer, you need to really consider your database design and make use of `ForeignKey` relationships. Having a foreign key as a `CharField` is not recommended.

I would suggest the following:

Change:

```
DCU_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=False)
```

To:

```
DCU = models.ForeignKey(dcu, null=True, blank=False)
```

Then you can query like so:

```
Meter_Mapping_Table.objects.filter(DCU=1).count()
```

> *Note: Also consider following [**Django's Naming Convention for Models**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style). As this will aid readability for other developers.*

Comment: Meter_Mapping_Table.objects.filter(DCU=1).count()    
 I'm also Know about this @Lewis but i have many dcu's under that dcu's i have many MU's in this methos i want to code for all dcu's but i need dynamic filter based on DCU_id & id in DCU tables and want to show that in frontend for that it's not working i tryed this .... and Thank You so much for trying to help me .